# repositories.ros.org status page not updated for 10 days

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Status pages for both M and K mention the page was generated 10 days ago, which sounds a kind of old. Is this intended?

- [Melodic](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/melodic_default.html)
  [image: image description]
- [Kinetic](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/kinetic_default.html)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324269/repositories.ros.org-status-page-not-updated-for-10-days/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2019-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit:

regarding the build farm: see [Security issue on ROS build farm](https://discourse.ros.org/t/security-issue-on-ros-build-farm/9342) for the reason the buildfarm is down.

[Key rotation for ROS 2 apt repositories](https://discourse.ros.org/t/key-rotation-for-ros-2-apt-repositories/9363) is related, but for now only the ROS 2 repositories are affected.

---

original:

> Is this intended?

well that depends how you look at it: `build.ros.org` has been down since May the 19th, so in a way this is to be expected.

From [status.ros.org](https://status.ros.org):

> Build.ros.org offline
>
> Investigating - Our Jenkins instance is having issues with running the management jobs. We're taking it offline until we can resolve the issue.
>
> May 19, 22:49 UTC

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-30**:
@nuclearsandwich: what is the prognosis for `build.ros.org`?

**Comment by [wxm](https://answers.ros.org/users/41136/wxm/) on 2019-06-02**:
Do we have an update on the buildfarm status? I couldn't find anything on ROS Answers and just created account on the new Jenkins instance. I keep getting build error emails, but can't see their status pages.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-02**:\

> just created account on the new Jenkins instance

there's most likely no point doing that: it's not going to be needed and that instance is most likely going to be reset at any time coming weeks.